# в чем разница между вызовами этих функций?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: разница функций]

**Вариант 1**

```
function createCounter(){
}
```

**Вариант 2**

```
const myFunctiion = function(){
}
```

Не понимаю в чем разница. и то и то вроде функция.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression

Comment: ну хотя бы в том что функция, объявленая как в варианте 1 доступна везде в своей области видимости, а в варианте 2 -- только ниже объявления (так же в области видимости). https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#definition -- пункт "способы объявления функции"

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта представляют собой функции, однако есть разница в их определении и использовании.

**Вариант 1** представляет собой определение функции с использованием **function declaration**. Это означает, что функция имеет имя (в данном случае "createCounter") и создается до выполнения любого кода в программе. Это означает, что функция может быть вызвана в любой части программы, даже до ее определения.

**Вариант 2** представляет собой определение функции с использованием **function expression**. В этом случае функция присваивается переменной (в данном случае "myFunction") и создается только при выполнении соответствующей строки кода. Это означает, что функция может быть вызвана только после ее определения.

В обоих случаях функции могут содержать код и параметры, а также возвращать значения. Разница заключается только в способе и времени их определения и вызова.

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/function-declaration-vs-function-expression/)

Comment: спасибо большое )